# How to install ati 4870 driver for linux (.run file)

Tags: linux, drivers

I have installed Linux Mint Gnome 64bit version.
I have downloaded `ati-driver-installer-10-9-x86_64.run` file.
But i don't know how can i install this file to my system :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run:

```
sudo sh ati-driver-installer-10-9-x86_64.run
```

and follow the instructions.

Comment: thanks working...this command and drivers links http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/previous/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx